# Magento 1.9 : removeitem action xml , remove css from specific page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, layout

I have an onestepcheckout module for magento and I need to remove all the css from the theme on my checkout page I need to remove this item

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myurl.com/skin/frontend/codazon_fastest/default/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myurl.com/skin/frontend/codazon_fastest/default/codazon/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" media="all" />
```

how i remove this? im trying this on onestepcheckout.xml:

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/bootstrap-theme.min.css</name></action>
```

and is not removing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can follow these steps:

1.Create a local.xml file in your theme layout folder.

2.You can copy this code (eg: here I remove styles.css from cart page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
         <reference name="head">
         <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action><!--Remove CSS from skin Folder-->
         </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

So you should replace "checkout_cart_index" with onestepcheckout block 's name.

Good luck and happy coding !!!

Comment: Tell me if or works ;)